# getting syntax error on import statement in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

**Import statement**:

```
import * as tst from ".//SCRIPT//CommonImport"
```

**launch.json**:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Current",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "outputCapture": "console",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\${config:debug-current.file}",
    "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
}
```

Comment: did you copy and paste? cause it may cause that

Comment: What is your Node version?

Comment: @JackBashford 10.16.0

Comment: if I run the command in the terminal it works. so maybe it doesn't include esm when launching

Comment: No, it probably doesn't - or it might not support that exact import syntax. Try something simple like `import { prop } from ".//SCRIPT//CommonImport"`.

Answer (score 1):

I added

```
"runtimeArgs": [ "-r", "esm" ]
```

to the configuration in launch.json